# Connection between exterior derivative of functions with differential of tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I try do unterstand the connection between to different concepts:

1) The differential of a function $f:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ between two manifolds at a point $p\in\mathcal{M}$ is defined as $$\mathrm{d}_{p}f:T_{p}\mathcal{\mathcal{M}}\to T_{f(p)}\mathcal{\mathcal{N}}$$
$$v\mapsto(h\mapsto v(h\circ f))$$

or in other words: $[\mathrm{d}_{p}f(v)](h)=v(h\circ f)$ for $h\in C^{\infty}(N)$

2) The exterior derivative of a function $f:\mathcal{M}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differential form of degree 1:
$$\mathrm{d}f:\mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})\to C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$$
$$X\mapsto \mathrm{d}f(X):=X(f),$$ where we have identified a vector field $X$ as a derivation $X:C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\to C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$.

Now to my question....How are (1) and (2) connected with each other? I can write
$$\mathrm{d}f(X)(p)=X(f)(p)= X_p(f)$$

where in the last step I have identified the vector field with the function $X:\mathcal{M}\to T\mathcal{M}$.

Is there a relation bewtween $\mathrm{d}_{p}f(X_{p})\in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ (which means: $\mathrm{d}_{p}f(X_{p}):C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$) and $X_p(f)\in\mathbb{R}$? It probably has to do something with the identification $T_{p}\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 1):

If I write momentarily $Df_p:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, I know that $Df_p(X_p)=a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big|_{f(p)}$ since $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ is spanned by $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big|_{f(p)}$ (where $t:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the standard coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$). To check who is this $a$, evaluate both sides on the function $t$: you get

$$Df_p(X_p)(t)=X_p(t\circ f)=X_p(f)=df_p(X_p)$$

from the left side and

$$a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{f(p)}t=a\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}\Big|_{f(p)}=a.$$

from the right side. So this rewrites finally as

$$Df_p(X_p)=df_p(X_p)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{f(p)}$$

giving you the wanted relation between the two differentials

$$df_p:T_pM\overset{Df_p}{\longrightarrow}T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}\overset{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}$$

where $\simeq$ is the canonical identification $a\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mapsto a$.